# LibGDX draw BitmapFont to intermediate location (spritebatch)

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to draw some text using BitmapFont to some
temporary location and then draw a portion of this location
to the final spritebatch. I was thinking about drawing
to a temporary spritebatch, but it's not possible to
draw spritebatch onto another one. How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a FrameBuffer. See my example below, you can draw whatever you want in the drawBuffer function and then draw it on the screen.

Hope this helps

--EDIT--

NOTE : you must have useGL20 = true; in your Application Configuration

```
public class SpaceMania extends Game  {
@Override
public void create() {
    setScreen(new ScreenView());
}

}

class ScreenView implements Screen{
    InputMultiplexer input;
    FrameBuffer buffer;

    SpriteBatch screenBatch;
    ShapeRenderer shape;

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
    //Draw Buffer
    drawBuffer();


    //Draw buffer to screen
    screenBatch.begin();
    screenBatch.draw(buffer.getColorBufferTexture(), 0,0,600,200);
    screenBatch.end();
    }

    public void drawBuffer(){
    buffer.begin();
    shape.begin(ShapeType.FilledCircle);
    shape.setColor(Color.RED);
    shape.filledCircle(50, 50, 50);
    shape.end();
    buffer.end();
    }
    @Override
    public void show() {
    buffer = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGBA8888, 200, 200,false);
    screenBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    shape = new ShapeRenderer();
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to write it into the pixmap temporarily?
When you want to draw it, you can load the pixmap into texture object.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Pixmaps

Comment: I would, but BitmapFont can only draw to spritebatch.